# Insert variable from one file to another in a yml file using Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to insert the content of a file called version.txt into this yaml template using Bash. Version.txt contains only one number. This is my script.

```
  version=`cat version.txt`
  echo $version
  ( 
    echo "cat <<EOF >final.yml";`
    cat endpoint-config.yml;
    echo "EOF";
  ) >temp.yml
  . temp.yml
  cat final.yml
```

The yml template looks like this

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineDeployment.schema.json
name: k-means-sparkml-mlflow-deployment
endpoint_name: k-means-endpoint
model:
  name: mlflow-k-means-model
  version: ${version}
  local_path: k_means_model
  model_format: mlflow
instance_type: Standard_DS2_v2
instance_count: 1
```

and I want the final.yml to look like this

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineDeployment.schema.json
name: k-means-sparkml-mlflow-deployment
endpoint_name: k-means-endpoint
model:
  name: mlflow-k-means-model
  version: 7
  local_path: k_means_model
  model_format: mlflow
instance_type: Standard_DS2_v2
instance_count: 1
```

but so far, it looks like this:

```
: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineDeployment.schema.json
name: k-means-sparkml-mlflow-deployment
endpoint_name: k-means-endpoint
model:
  name: mlflow-k-means-model
  version: 7
  local_path: k_means_model
  model_format: mlflow
instance_type: Standard_DS2_v2
instance_count: 1EOF
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're going to use bash variable substitution, then the template can't contain variables you don't want substituted. `$schema` is a bash variable, which is being substituted with the empty string.  Escaping the dollar, e.g. `\$schema` in the template ought to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @Gene, that worked! I have one more question. Do you know how to remove the EOF at the end of the final.yml?

Comment: I really wouldn't do the substitution this way.  `bash` is essentially treating the whole template as a command line.  This is error prone and unsafe.  Use  ` bash` string substitution, `sed` or even better a real template facility like `m4` or `python` or even `cpp`.